# How does the division theorem hold if $a<b$ for $a=qb+r$? ($q,r$ = integers, and $0\leq r<b$)

Tags: proof-explanation

My understanding of the division theorem: 
Let $a,b$ be integers, $b>0$. Then there are unique integers q,r such that $a=qb+r$, and $0\leq r<b$

Is this supposed to hold for any arbitrarily chosen integer values for $a$ and $b$?

Example: $a= 1, b =5$. 
Then $1=5q +r$. If $q$ is supposed to be an integer, and $r$ cannot be negative and must $<b$, then unless I'm missing something very basic this statement cannot hold. So where has my understanding of the division theorem gone wrong?

Comment: Yes, $q$ is an integer, so $q=0$ is possible, and even $q<0$.

Comment: In your example, the unique $q$ and $r$ are $0$ and $1$, respectively.